# Analysis of Point cloud from a cow

Tags: c++, math, 3d, point-cloud-library

I'm reading a paper that analyse the shape of pigs or cows.

There is a part of which I can't understand enter image description here
[image]
How do I calculate the above 7 major points ?

There are many points in the point cloud and I'm not sure for example how calculate the circumference of cross section parallel to y-z plane ?

How do I select those points ?

enter image description here

[image]

Comment: _There are many points in the point cloud and I'm not sure for example how calculate the circumference of cross section parallel to y-z plane?_ Choose a value `x` and a tolerance `eps`. Collect all points with p.x in [x - eps, x + eps]. Construct a 2d convex polygon for the collected points (in y-z plane). (Google for "convex hull".) Determine it's length as the approximation of the circumference.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Thanks so much I got it. Can you please explain what about other parameters the 7 ones that are mentioned above ? You can provide an answer, by the way I gave you a plus 1

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Can I share with you some ideas in the chat ?